# New path added to matlab does not get saved permanently

Tags: matlab

I add a new path to matlab using File -> Set path, but it seems to get deleted every time I close matlab, and I have to add it back again. Using addpath and savepath from command line does not save it permanently either. How do I make matlab permanently remember the new path?

MATLAB Version 7.9.0.529 (R2009b) 64 bit on Windows 10 64 bit Home edition

Comment: `savepath` should save your current path so it is reloaded next time. Unless you have multiple pathdef files. You could also have a startup file that resets the path to some standard?

Comment: What are you doing with a version of Matlab that's 11 years out of date? Have you tried running Matlab as an administrator and trying? Might be that older versions of Matlab are saving the path list to a protected directory.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think multiple pathdefs is what is going on, but I don't know exactly what is happening. The first time I tried this it had shown me a dialog box that said whether I wanted to save the path information at some subfolder in C:\users, since the path information in c:\program files cannot be overwritten. I just clicked yes because I thought it would allow me to add new paths permanently, but apparently that's not what happened. Now I can't remember what exactly that dialog box said, nor make it appear again. I don't know what file it saved the information in in C:\users either

Comment: Something like `which pathdef -all` should show you a list of all your pathdef files on your path. Check also MATLAB’s startup directory (whatever the active directory is when you first start MATLAB up).

Comment: @CrisLuengo it shows two paths, the one in C:\program files has `% Shadowed ` next to it. What does this mean?

Comment: The first one is the one that is executed when you run the function. The other one isn’t. That’s what shadowed means. Not accessible. I think maybe the first one is the one that you are saving to, but that may not be visible when booting MATLAB, so it’s the shadowed one that actually is run.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Is it safe to manually edit the shadowed one? A comment in the file says not to modify it

Comment: Yes, you can edit it. It will be overwritten by `savepath`, but apparently that isn't the case for you. :) You could also delete the one that is shadowing it. I looked at the docs for `savepath`, it chooses weirdly where to save. I would have thought there's always only one of those files, but no.